# Combining redundant nodes in a phylo object

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I have a phylo-object, zphylo, in R which if plotted looks like this:

```
library(phytools)
plotTree(zphylo) + nodelabels()
```

[image]

Only the nodes labelled 85 and 56 are informative for the phylogenic structure. The other nodes get in the way and I'd like to combine all other nodes that fall on the same branch. (For example, I'd like to combine {31, 83, 84}, {89..92}, {86..88} and {35..44}).

Are you able to help with this please?

Here's the zphylo object for reproducibility:

```
> dput(zphylo)
structure(list(edge = structure(c(31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 31L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 31L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 31L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 31L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
56L, 31L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 31L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 31L, 67L, 
31L, 68L, 69L, 31L, 70L, 71L, 31L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 31L, 75L, 76L, 
31L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 31L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 85L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 31L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 31L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 100L, 31L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 31L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 
107L, 108L, 31L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 31L, 31L, 113L, 114L, 
115L, 116L, 31L, 117L, 118L, 31L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
31L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 31L, 131L, 132L, 
133L, 31L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 31L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 31L, 
141L, 142L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 1L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 2L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
3L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 4L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 5L, 6L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 
62L, 63L, 7L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 8L, 67L, 9L, 68L, 69L, 10L, 70L, 
71L, 11L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 12L, 75L, 76L, 13L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 14L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 15L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
92L, 16L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 17L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 18L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 19L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 20L, 109L, 
110L, 111L, 112L, 21L, 22L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 23L, 117L, 
118L, 24L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 25L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 
127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 26L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 27L, 134L, 135L, 
136L, 137L, 28L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 29L, 141L, 142L, 30L), .Dim = c(141L, 
2L)), edge.length = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 
9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 
9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 
9.09090909090909, 11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 
11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 
11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 75, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 50, 50, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
14.2857142857143, 14.2857142857143, 14.2857142857143, 14.2857142857143, 
14.2857142857143, 14.2857142857143, 14.2857142857143, 12.5, 12.5, 
12.5, 15.625, 15.625, 15.625, 15.625, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 
12.5, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 100, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 
12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 25, 25, 25, 25, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333), 
    Nnode = 112L, node.label = c("0", "4025", "10357", "31510", 
    "1416", "8358", "12834", "14606", "19241", "23013", "23623", 
    "29010", "29310", "29704", "7625", "8337", "8654", "19681", 
    "25143", "26795", "26949", "35868", "5195", "22012", "22937", 
    "3664", "30536", "35564", "2763", "14166", "18081", "27368", 
    "32166", "7623", "21118", "27594", "1414", "1503", "8264", 
    "2135", "32928", "244", "9549", "18007", "2313", "19022", 
    "608", "8490", "9218", "21872", "29443", "31220", "3126", 
    "9127", "13016", "13066", "14216", "18273", "13269", "18768", 
    "22940", "35317", "4746", "12129", "32304", "35168", "4925", 
    "12775", "16342", "33395", "2045", "9118", "10592", "1323", 
    "26998", "30246", "31785", "32344", "1143", "9659", "17624", 
    "30091", "6183", "16281", "24250", "37032", "2134", "24907", 
    "7982", "11650", "12535", "15734", "23221", "6812", "9742", 
    "16971", "18383", "23751", "29185", "36304", "5013", "19852", 
    "21927", "4384", "24955", "26205", "30072", "6634", "10033", 
    "18693", "964", "27759"), tip.label = c("38936", "37134", 
    "38161", "34243", "38130", "30535", "36657", "38381", "8626", 
    "14088", "37592", "29331", "23773", "35300", "32270", "38133", 
    "39497", "40145", "24748", "36138", "32747", "64", "38112", 
    "36973", "38400", "39197", "24650", "32376", "28115", "39503"
    )), .Names = c("edge", "edge.length", "Nnode", "node.label", 
"tip.label"), class = "phylo", order = "cladewise")
```

Comment: Provide the `dput()` of your data, not the formatted displayed value. Right now it's not in a very [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You might also consider posting these sorts of questions here: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. What's the policy on cross-posting? Should I delete this question and ask it again on the bioinformatics forum?

Comment: @Sigurgeir Cross-posting is discouraged, but in the future, you may prefer to post on the bioinformatics stackexchange site as it's a more appropriate place for such topics. For cross-posting details see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `ape::collapse.singles` to collapse those nodes that link to only one branch.

```
library(ape)
plotTree(ape::collapse.singles(zphylo)) + nodelabels()
```